# Count and access each checked row object in UITableView when clicked on a button outside the tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am a newbie to IOS development. I am having a UITableView and a separate button(Outside the table) to save the checked rows. Once the rows are checked, I want to count and access each row object on a button click (Save). This way, I will save each row, one by one, on the server.

I think I can count the rows by using `[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows].count`, but not sure have to access the row objects as I am not inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Since the rows are just visual representations, do you really mean you need to save the data that **matches** the selected rows?  If so, the array of index paths should let you access whatever storage you used when you were in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but the problem is that I add checkmarks inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`and once I finish doing this, there could be various cells which are checked. At the end, what I would like to have is that a user would select the **save** button which is not a part of the tableview and then, we would consider the rows which are check marked and process them on the server. What do you think? Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: I think that when you check a cell, you should save that information in the data that you use to populate the cell and then search the data instead of the table.  If you'd like to post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I might be able to say something more specific.